# React: how to have many buttons open the same popup component without using state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, rerender

I have a simple React site that is a simple parody of streaming video sites. I’ve .map a large array of objects that include (project Title, description, video links, image link, tags) to generate a bunch of different “<ProjectTile/>” that each need to open the same popup component (<ProjectDetails/> and send their information to it.

I was originally using 2 useState that was passed to each <ProjectTile/>, one to control the visibility of the <ProjectDetails/> component, and one to store the clicked project information for the <ProjectDetails/> component to reference.

This worked well, but it causes all of the tiles to re-render in the DOM when 1 tile is clicked which creates a flicker when all the tiles have to be regenerated by the map function of the array.

Is there a better way to do this??

here is the <ProjectTile/>

```
import React from "react";

import ProjectAward from "../Project Award/projectAward"


import "./app.css";

//import components
const ProjectTile = ({ setRevealDetails, setSelectedProject, project, projectTitle, projectText, imgSrc, award }) => {

  

  return (
    <div key={Math.random()} onClick={() => {setSelectedProject(project);setRevealDetails(true)}}>
      <div className="project-card" >
        {award.map((item) => (
          <ProjectAward key={Math.random()} award={item} />
        ))}
        <div className="project-card-text">
          <h2>
            {projectTitle}
            <div className="project-card-text-horizontal-line"></div>
          </h2>

          <h3>{projectText}</h3>
        </div>
        <img
          className="project-card-img"
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          left="0%"
          effect="blur"
          src={imgSrc}
          alt={`image for ${projectTitle}`}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectTile;
```

here is the <ProjectDetails/>

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./app.css";

import ProjectVideo from "../Project Video/projectVideo"

const ProjectDetails = ({ selectedProject, setRevealDetails }) => {

  const [vidNumber, setVidNumber] = useState(0);

  //functions
  const nextVid = () => {
    if (vidNumber < selectedProject.projectVideos.length - 1) {
      setVidNumber(vidNumber + 1);
    } else {
      setVidNumber(0);
    }
  };
  const previousVid = () => {
    if (vidNumber !== 0) {
      setVidNumber(vidNumber - 1);
    } else {
      setVidNumber(selectedProject.projectVideos.length - 1);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="project-detail-page-background">
        <div className="project-detail-page">
          <div className="close-project-detail-page" onClick={() => {
            setVidNumber(0);
            setRevealDetails(false);
          }}><i className="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></div>
          <div className="project-detail-page-container">
            {selectedProject.projectTitle}

            <div className="video-panel-iframe">
              <ProjectVideo videoSrc={selectedProject.projectVideos[vidNumber]} />
            </div>
            {selectedProject.projectVideos.length <= 1 ? (
              <div></div>
            ) : (
              <div className="video-bttn-container">
                <div className="video-previous-bttn" onClick={previousVid}>
                  <i className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div className="video-panel-number">
                  {`${vidNumber + 1} of ${selectedProject.projectVideos.length}`}
                </div>
                <div className="video-next-bttn" onClick={nextVid}>
                  <i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me clarify the answer to your question

if you don't want to use state, you can use a ref to the popup component and then manipulate it directly.
Example

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import Popup from './Popup';

function App() {
const popupRef = useRef(null);
const handleClick = () => {
popupRef.current.open();
}

return(
<div>
<button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
<Popup ref={popupRef} />
</div>
);
}
```

And now after checking your code yes there is a better way to do this, instead of using two state variables and data  component, you can use a single state variable to store the selected project and then pass it as a prop to the  component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import ProjectAward from "../Project Award/projectAward";
import ProjectDetails from "../Project Details/projectDetails";

import "./app.css";

const ProjectTile = ({ project }) => {
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  const handleTileClick = () => {
    setShowDetails(true);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleTileClick}>
      <div className="project-card">
        {project.award.map((item) => (
          <ProjectAward key={item} award={item} />
        ))}
        <div className="project-card-text">
          <h2>
            {project.projectTitle}
            <div className="project-card-text-horizontal-line"></div>
          </h2>

          <h3>{project.projectText}</h3>
        </div>
        <img
          className="project-card-img"
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          left="0%"
          effect="blur"
          src={project.imgSrc}
          alt={`image for ${project.projectTitle}`}
        />
      </div>
      {showDetails && (
        <ProjectDetails
          project={project}
          onClose={() => setShowDetails(false)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectTile;
```

we use a single state variable showDetails to control the visibility of the  component. We also pass the project object as a prop to the  component.

In the  component, we set the showDetails state to true when the tile is clicked. We also conditionally render the  component based on the value of showDetails. When rendering the  component, we pass in the project object as a prop and also a callback function to handle the closing of the popup.

In the  component, we receive the project object as a prop and use it to display project details. When closing the popup, we call the callback function passed in as a prop to update the showDetails state in .

This way, only one tile is re-rendered when it is clicked and there is no flicker due to the regeneration of all tiles by the map function.

Comment: stupid me, i didn’t think about keeping the project details component as a child of the project tile. Im so stuck on keeping all the components in the main App.jsx that i didn’t think about your option. I now gotta look up how to use callback functions as props :-)

Comment: actually, unfortunately that did not work, because now the <ProjectDetails/> renders inside the <ProjectTile/> which makes it impossible (as far as I know) to properly keep the <ProjectDetails/> as a fullpage component.